# DNS points to the right IP, but I can't SSH based on DNS

Tags: networking, ssh, dns

I can connect remotely to my system using the IP address, the DNS returns the proper IP, but I can't connect via a DNS record.

i.e.

```
matt@pontus:~$ ssh fake.myDnsExample.com
ssh: connect to host fake.myDnsExample.com port 22: Network is unreachable
matt@pontus:~$ nslookup fake.myDnsExample.com
Server:     134.117.aaa.bbb
Address:    134.117.aaa.bbb#53

Non-authoritative answer:
fake.myDnsExample.com   canonical name = myDnsExample.com.
Name:   myDnsExample.com
Address: 50.100.XXX.YYY

matt@pontus:~$ ssh 50.100.XXX.YYY

               *connects*
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, this system is not in the DMZ but ports 22 and 80 are forwarded to it, it used to work (not sure what changed), and this also doesn't work locally, but again I can ssh to localhost.

Might this be an issue with Ubuntu?  I don't imagine my router would interfere with this.

Comment: Connect using verbose mode (`ssh -v`). See if the IP matches.

Comment: Ack, turns out the system I was testing it from (remotely) did have a bad entry in ''/etc/host', and ''ssh -v'' pointed that out right away.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there might be some issues in DNS resolving. try adding the DNS name and corresponding ip in /etc/hosts file and check.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a hack though?  It'd only work internally I suspect, and I'd have to enter every DNS entry into this manually.